# No solutions to a matrix inequality?

Tags: linear-algebra, stochastic-matrices

If $A$ is a stochastic matrix, then $A$ is entry-wise nonnegative and $Ae = e$, i.e., $(1,e)$ is a right eigenpair for $A$.

Is it true that there exists a vector $b$ such that

$$(A - I)x \geq b$$

has no solutions in $x$?  If so, is there a simple proof?

Motivation: I've been trying to construct an answer to [another question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/8556/) using linear programming duality (as the OP implies he is interested in).  If my reasoning is correct, this is the only step I need to complete the argument.  I feel like this should be an easy question to answer, but I've been working on it for a while with no success.

Comment: Wouldn't you have to say how it is you are comparing vectors? What does $v\geq w$ mean in your vector space? Do you mean $||(A−I)x||≥||b||$, under the usual norm of $\mathbb{R}^n$, perhaps? Or that ever entry of $(A-I)x$ is greater than or equal to the corresponding entry of $b$?

Comment: I believe inequalities between vectors are meant to be taken componentwise here, i.e. $a \ge b \Leftrightarrow a_i \ge b_i \forall i$.

Comment: @Arturo: Fanfan is correct.  Componentwise comparison for vectors is standard in linear programming.  Since that's where I normally work with vectors I tend to forget that there are other ways of interpreting statements like $(A - I)x \geq b$.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your inequality $(A-I)x \ge b$ has no solutions in $x$ as soon as $b>0$. Indeed, any potential solution would have to satisfy $A x \ge  x + b$ and, since rows of $A$ are nonnegative and sum to one, each element of vector $Ax$ is a convex combination of the components of $x$, which must be less than $x_{max}$, the largest component of $x$. On the other hand, at least one element of $x+b$ is greater than $x_{max}$, which proves the impossibility.

By the way, applying [Farkas' Lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Farkas%27_lemma) to this impossible system shows that the following always admits solutions in y
$$y^T (A-I) = 0, y \ge 0 \text{ and } y^T b > 0$$
which expresses the fact that $A$ necessarily admits a nonnegative left eigenvector with eigenvalue $1$ (the last inequality ensures that $y$ is nonzero).

Comment: Thanks, Fanfan.  That's exactly what I needed.  And, as you probably realize, you've given another answer to the question I was working on: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/8556/.  You can use LP duality as well as Farkas' Lemma to show that same system you give here has a nonzero solution.