# Eigenvalue locations for various matrix types?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I'm relatively new to linear algebra and so far I'm aware of at least three types of (real valued) matrices where we can get a guarantee about where the eigenvalues live.

Symmetric ($A^T = A $)  $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$

Skew-Symmetric ($A^T = -A $) $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}$ where Re{$\lambda$}$=0$

Orthogonal ($Q^TQ=I$) $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}$ where $|\lambda|=1$

I'm curious whether there are many other examples of real matrix types (that aren't subsets of the types listed above) where we get similar guarantees about where their eigenvalues sit in the complex plane. (For example, is there a type of real valued matrix that is neither symmetric, skew symmetric, nor orthogonal, but whose eigenvalues can still be proven to lie on the unit circle?) Thanks!

Comment: You might like [Gershgorin circle theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gershgorin_circle_theorem), and also [stochastic matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_matrix): see [Proof that the largest eigenvalue of a stochastic matrix is 1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/40320/proof-that-the-largest-eigenvalue-of-a-stochastic-matrix-is-1). Methods of [root location of polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Properties_of_polynomial_roots) apply to [companion matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Companion_matrix) or any matrix whose characteristic polynomial is known.

Comment: Thanks! Gershgorin's circle theorem is exactly the sort of "eigenvalue constraining" theorem I was looking for!