# Show that columns of PageRank matrix sum to 1

Tags: linear-algebra, page-rank

Where the matrix A is replaced with
$$G=\alpha A+(1-\alpha)\frac{1}{n}ee^T$$

Is it a sufficient condition a matrix is  stochastic if the largest eigenvalue is 1? Or that in this case since A is stochastic and the largest eigenvalue of G is 1, that G is also stochastic, and thereby the  columns sum  to  1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first the largest eigenvalue of a stochastic matrix is indeed $1$ but this is not a sufficient to prove that a matrix is stochastic (consider for instance add to zero. Take
$
M=\begin{bmatrix}1& 0 & 1\\0&1& 0\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix}
$ which has maximal eigenvalue 1 but isn't stochastic (see also e.g. [Proof that the largest eigenvalue of a stochastic matrix is $1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/40320/proof-that-the-largest-eigenvalue-of-a-stochastic-matrix-is-1))).

Now to show that $G$ is stochastic (assuming $A$ is stochastic), just apply the definitions:
$$
\begin{align*}
\sum_j G_{i,j} & = \sum_j  (\alpha A_{i,j} + {(1-\alpha)\over n} ee^{T}_{i,j})\\
&=  \alpha \sum_j A_{i,j} + {(1-\alpha)\over n} \sum_j  ee^{T}_{i,j}\\
&= \alpha \times 1 + {(1-\alpha)\over n} \sum_j  ee^{T}_{i,j} \\
&\text{(since $A$ is stochastic)}\\
&= \alpha + {(1-\alpha)\over n}  \sum_j 1 \\
&= \alpha + (1-\alpha) = 1
\end{align*}
$$

Does this answer your question?

Comment: It does, thanks!