# If a irreducible, stochastic, aperiodic matrix is not diagonalizable, can it converge on power method??

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods

In some linear algebra books/blogs, I have found that a power method can be done only on diagonalizable matrix with a dominant eigenvalue. 
In other books/blogs, I have found that a irreducible, stochastic, aperiodic matrix can converge on the power method. 
I am working with irreducible, stochastic, aperiodic and it may be diagonalizable sometime or not sometimes. I want to know if it would always converge on the power iteration method.  I also want to know why a non-diagonal matrix with a dominant eigenvalue can not converge?

Comment: Of course the power method can be "done" on any matrix, and the issue is whether it gives useful information about "a dominant eigenvalue."  But I think I don't quite know the crux of your problem.  If $M$ is [stochastic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_matrix), its [largest eigenvalue is 1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/40320/proof-that-the-largest-eigenvalue-of-a-stochastic-matrix-is-1).

Comment: You might want to check the Perron-Frobenius theory, a matrix with positive or null entries has its largest eigenvalue positive and real with a positive eigenvector. This is very compatible with the power method.

Comment: I know, But why on most of the blogs it is said that the matrix should be diagonalizable for power method to work? I don't get that. Even in wikipedia, the blog "Power iteration" states same.  @LutzL

Comment: It is a reasonable Question, but it would be improved by pointing out a blog where "it is said that the matrix should be diagonalizable".  I think this might be the least important of the matrix properties listed (for using the power method), and it would help to identify whether convergence of the *eigenvector* or of the *eigenvalue* is important to you.

Comment: I don't read the Wikipedia article "Power iteration" to say the matrix "should be  diagonalizable for the power method to work."  Indeed see further down in the article for [application of the power method to non-diagonalizable matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_iteration#Applications).  What is true is that the analysis is easier for diagonalizable matrices, and frequently the algorithm is applied to such matrices (e.g. real symmetric cases).  I read your Question to be mainly interested in stochastic matrices, but on closer study I can see I might be mistaken about that.

Answer (score 1):

The power method can be used to analyze matrices that are not diagonalizable. The way to do it is using a similar transformation, called Jordan decomposition (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_normal_form)), where unlike the eigenvalue decomposition, Jordan decomposition always exists.