# How can I prove that $I-\gamma A$ is invertible?

Tags: linear-algebra, stochastic-processes, markov-chains, markov-process

Let $A\in[0,1]^{n\times n}$ be row stochastic matrix. Let $\gamma \in(0,1)$ be arbitrary.
Then how can I prove that $(I-\gamma A)^{-1}$ (where $I$ is the identity matrix) exists?

Answer (score 4):

If $(I- \gamma A)x=0$, then $Ax= \frac{1}{\gamma}x.$ Now suppose that $x \ne 0$, then $\frac{1}{\gamma}$ is an eigenvalue of $A$. Since $A$ is a row stochastic matrix, $\frac{1}{\gamma} \le 1,$ a contradiction. Thus $x=0.$ Hence $I- \gamma A$ is invertible.

Comment: How can I prove that the spectral radius of A is one?

Comment: @shashankranjan Check this out: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/40320/proof-that-the-largest-eigenvalue-of-a-stochastic-matrix-is-1